# Why is a space being inserted into the Mathematical annotation of xlabel?

Tags: r, math, annotations

This problem has been bothering me for days. I use the `expression(paste())` construct to produce mathematical annotation in labels, but there is a space being inserted between the Greek letter and the normal letter (the μ m).

I have insufficient reputation to post images, so here is a text version of how it looks:

```
Pore Volume (μ m^3)
```

Here is the code I use to generate the label:

```
png(width=6, height=3)
par(cex=0.7)
boxplot(test1,xlab=(expression(paste("Pore Volume (" ,mu,m^3, ")", sep=""))))
```

Is there a problem with the code?

Comment: does `plot(1,1, t="n",xlab=expression("Pore Volume ("*mu*m^3*")"))` work better for you?

Comment: try `paste0` as well

Comment: Thx Phil, I have tried the 1st method you suggested, still a gap in between. I will check the paste0.

Comment: I don't see a gap with any of the methods, you should probably provide further info on your configuration (R version, OS) and experiment with different devices (e.g. Cairo).

Comment: I used MacOS for the compliling and exactly I used the CairoPDF and CairoPNG both, but the problem is still there.

Comment: BTW, paste0 doesn't work somehow.      xlab=(paste0("Pore Volume (",mu, m^3,")", collapse = NULL))), error is "object mu not found. And  xlab=(expression(paste0("Pore Volume (",mu, m^3,")", collapse = NULL))))  gave "  Error: unexpected symbol "

Comment: Still didn't get the solution, but found the related link of this problem. It seems a bug in the "Cairo" Package. http://webmail.dev411.com/t/r/r-help/1219myegvp/r-cairopdf-and-greek-letter-spacing

Comment: According to the website link, this is the compatibility bug of "Cairo" package, so I gave up using the "Cairo" and save it as normal png.

Comment: @Joanna Please post this as the answer to your own question so that it will be more visible to others having the same problem.

Comment: @Joanna Welcome to StackOverflow. I have made some simple edits to your question to make it a little clearer for future readers. Please feel free to roll-back the edits if I have altered your intent.